# Exclude a category from block editor's category widget

Tags: categories, widgets, block-editor

I have added category widget form block editor.

[image]

It shows the list of all categories.

I want to exclude a category from that list.

[image]

How can I exclude a category from this list?

Comment: Which list? Your screenshot shows an arrow pointing at the categories block/widget, is it the block/widget that you're trying to remove? Or have I misunderstood? Please use the edit link under the tags on your qeustion to make your question less ambiguous and clearer

Comment: Which list? This widget shows or output a list of categories. I want to exclude a category from that list. I have edited the question. Please take a look and let me know if you can help me on that.